# compiler optimization does not respect `-pthreads`

Tags: c, pthreads, global-variables, volatile

I compiled the code:

```
extern int x;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    while (x != 1) {}
    return 0;
}
```

with

```
$ clang -c -O3 -pthread -emit-llvm main.c
$ llvm-dis main.bc
```

And when I examined the resulting bitcode I was surprised to see the following optimization:

- from `while (x != 1) {}` to `if (x != 1) while (1);`

Here are the relevant bitcode file lines:

```
$ sed -n '10,16p;17q' main.ll
entry:
  %.pr = load i32, i32* @x, align 4, !tbaa !2
  %cmp = icmp eq i32 %.pr, 1
  br i1 %cmp, label %while.end.split, label %while.cond

while.cond:                                       ; preds = %entry, %while.cond
  br label %while.cond
```

What if some other thread changed `x`?

Comment: When different threads access the same non-atomic object without synchronization, the behavior of the program is undefined. So there is nothing wrong with this optimization.

Comment: Every [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) is compiled in isolation, the compiler just don't know anything about other translation units. If the compiler doesn't know anything about other threads, it can't take them into account. If you want to prohibit a variable from being optimized, define it as `volatile`.

Comment: If I declare `x` to be `volatile` the optimization is cancelled, why doesn't the compiler assume that **every** global variable *is* volatile? or at least warns about that?

Comment: And while [the *as-if* rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) is specific for C++, the same really applies to C.

Comment: Assumptions are often wrong. And in C you should not pay the price for something you don't use or need. If you know that a global variable might be used from multiple threads it's your responsibility as a programmer to make sure the access to that variable is protected, synchronized and to tell the compiler about it.